# How to prove the associative property of min-plus matrix multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, associativity

According to *Zwick, Uri*, [**All pairs shortest paths using bridging sets and rectangular matrix multiplication**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/567112.567114), J. ACM 49, No. 3, 289-317 (2002). [ZBL1326.05157](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1326.05157). and [Min-plus matrix multiplication (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-plus_matrix_multiplication), Min-plus matrix multiplication, also known as the distance product is defined as:

> Given two $n \times n$ matrices $A = (a_{ij})$ and $B = (b_{ij})$, their distance product $C = (c_{ij}) = A \star B$ is defined as an $n \times n$ matrix such that $c_{ij} = \min_{k=1}^n \{a_{ik} + b_{kj}\}$. This is standard matrix multiplication for the semi-ring of tropical numbers in the min convention.

One of matrix multiplication property is that it is associative, that is: $(AB)C = A(BC)$. The proof of this property in normal case is well known, however in min-plus algebra, I cannot find any reasoning explanation.

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Associativity holds for multiplication of matrices over a semiring.  The proof is the same as the usual one for matrices over a field - none of the additional properties of a field are used.